# Homeomorphic balls in orthant $[0,\infty)^n$.

Tags: general-topology, euclidean-geometry

> Define the upper half space as
>   $$ \mathbb{H}^n := [0,\infty)^n$$ 
>    $B_r(x) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is the open ball of radius $r$ around $x$. If $B_r(x) \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^n \not= 0 $, then I believe
>
> $$ B_r(0) \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^n \text{ and } B_r(x) \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^n \text{ are homeomorphic.} $$

How does one show this? I can do this in the $n=2$ case by identifying with $\mathbb{C}$, then a process of radial scaling, translation, and squaring. It is messy to generalize this...

Comment: Upper half-space is usually defined as $\mathbb{H}^n = \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \times [0, \infty)$. $[0, \infty)^n$ could perhaps be more appropriately be called *nonnegative orthant*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true, not even for $n=2$:

[image]

$B_r(x)\cap\partial\Bbb H^n$ (the $\color{red}{\mathrm{red}}$ lines) is connected on the left, but not so on the right.

Comment: Sorry, how is the right side not connected?

Comment: @CWL Is this new image helping?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot .